# SwiftUI TextField shifting in VStack on focus of top TextField only

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to Swift, and App development in general.
I have the following code for a login screen. When I click the top input field, popping the keyboard. It is shifting up the View. That part I don't mind. It if pushing the TextField out of the VStack though.

[image]

If I then click the second InputField, everything shifts back

```
import SwiftUI

struct Login_Sign_Up: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ColorPalette.greenDark.ignoresSafeArea()
            LoginScreen()
            .frame(width: 320, height: 270)
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }
        
    }
}

// well.. where we would login
struct LoginScreen: View {
  @State private var email = ""
  @State private var password = ""

  var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          VStack(spacing: 16.0) {
              Text("Login")
              TextField("Email", text: $email)
                  .frame(width: 260)
                  .padding()
                  .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(ColorPalette.greenDarker, lineWidth: 2)
                   )
              TextField("Password", text: $password)
                  .frame(width: 260)
                  .padding()
                  .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(ColorPalette.greenDarker, lineWidth: 2)
                   )
              Button("Sign In") {
                  // TODO: Sign in the user
              }
              Text("Don't have an account? Sign up")
              .onTapGesture {
                  // TODO: Navigate to the sign up screen
              }
        }
      }
      .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
  }
}
```

I tried putting padding on various elements in the VStack, tried adding ignoreSafeArea on the VStack, and anywhere else I could put it without the compiler complaining. Tried adding Spacer() above, below, and both around the Text() call. Also tried a lot of googling, but I'm sure I don't know how to phrase my question well with SwiftUI just yet!

FINAL CODE THAT WORKED FOR ME

```
import SwiftUI

struct Login_Sign_Up: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoginScreen()
    }
}

// well.. where we would login
struct LoginScreen: View {
  @State private var email = ""
  @State private var password = ""

  var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          ZStack {
              ColorPalette.green.ignoresSafeArea()
              VStack(spacing: 20) {
                  Text("Login")
                  TextField("Email", text: $email)
                      .frame(width: 260)
                      .padding()
                      .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(ColorPalette.greenDarker, lineWidth: 2)
                       )
                  TextField("Password", text: $password)
                      .frame(width: 260)
                      .padding()
                      .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(ColorPalette.greenDarker, lineWidth: 2)
                       )
                  Button("Sign In") {
                      // TODO: Sign in the user
                  }
                  Text("Don't have an account? Sign up")
                  .onTapGesture {
                      // TODO: Navigate to the sign up screen
                  }
              }
              .frame(width: 320, height: 270, alignment: .center)
              .background(Color.white)
              .cornerRadius(20)
          }
          
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving .frame(..) inside the NavigationView closure resolves the issue:

```
struct Login_Sign_Up: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ColorPalette.greenDark.ignoresSafeArea()
            LoginScreen()
        }
    }
}

struct LoginScreen: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 16.0) {
                Text("Login")
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .frame(width: 260)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(ColorPalette.greenDarker, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
                TextField("Password", text: $password)
                    .frame(width: 260)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(ColorPalette.greenDarker, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
                Button("Sign In") {
                    // TODO: Sign in the user
                }
                Text("Don't have an account? Sign up")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // TODO: Navigate to the sign up screen
                    }
            }
            .frame(width: 320, height: 270, alignment: .center) // << use alignment
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }
        // .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)  // << remove
    }
}
```

Also remove `.ignoresSafeArea()`, you don't need them.

Comment: This worked! To get the background color I had set on the 'parent' view that was rendering the LoginScreen view.. I did have to move that zstack out out the parent view and into login screen struct.. But your changes by themselves fixed the issue OP is regarding. Thank you so much, we won't talk about how much time I spent on that!